# Angular2 Routing: How to navigate to a child view from a service instead of routerLink?

Tags: angular2-routing

I have a problem when trying to navigate to a child view by code using the router object within my component :

```
this.router.navigate(['./details']); //Error: Cannot match any routes: 'details'
```

But within my template using routerLink, it works :

   Test me

I need to do the same thing but within the component using the router.navigate method. My component is displayed within another one in a routerOutlet, I have the following sub routing config :

```
export const HOME_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [{path: '',outlet: 'route1',component: DashboardComponent,pathMatch: 'full'},
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        outlet: 'route1',
        component: DashboardComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'tasks',
        outlet: 'route1',
        component: TasksComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '',component: TasksListComponent,pathMatch: 'full'},
            { path: 'list',component: TasksListComponent},
            { path: 'details', component: TasksDetailsComponent },
            { path: 'view', component: TasksListComponent },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

And I'm trying to display the TasksDetailsComponent from the TasksListComponent, my relative url is "http://localhost:8000/home/(route1:tasks)

Any help is very appreciated
Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

then within your component

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

then

```
this.router.navigate(['./details'], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

Comment: @mthkhaled feel free to accept this answer if it works for you